# iphone - UIViewController header view errors

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, header

So to give a little background:

I've an app that has a UITableViewController- (ContactDetailViewController)
In this view at the top, I require a few labels and buttons, followed by a group style tableview.
So I've created a nib file containing these elements. (ContactHeaderView.xib)
Then in the viewDidLoad of ContactDetailViewController I've loaded this nib as the headerView. See implementation file below:

```
#import "ContactDetailViewController.h"
#import "DisplayInfoViewController.h"
#import "ActionViewController.h"

@implementation ContactDetailViewController

@synthesize name;
@synthesize date;
@synthesize nextAction;
@synthesize nameLabel;
@synthesize usernameLabel;
@synthesize nextActionTextField;
@synthesize dateLabel;
@synthesize contactInfoButton;
@synthesize backgroundInfoButton;
@synthesize actionDoneButton;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


#pragma mark Table view methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return 3;
}

- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0){
        UIViewController *chv = [[[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ContactHeaderView" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    //  self.nameLabel.text = self.name;
        return chv.view;
    }else{
        return nil;
    }
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 300.0;
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Set up the cell...

    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    // AnotherViewController *anotherViewController = [[AnotherViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AnotherView" bundle:nil];
    // [self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController];
    // [anotherViewController release];
}


/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/



- (void)dealloc {
    [name release];
    [date release];
    [nextAction release];
    [nameLabel release];
    [usernameLabel release];
    [nextActionTextField release];
    [dateLabel release];
    [contactInfoButton release];
    [backgroundInfoButton release];
    [actionDoneButton release];
    [super dealloc];
}

-(IBAction)displayContactInfo:(id)sender{

    DisplayInfoViewController *divc = [[DisplayInfoViewController alloc] init];
    divc.textView = self.nextAction;
    divc.title = @"Contact Info";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:divc animated:YES];
    [divc release];
}

-(IBAction)displayBackgroundInfo:(id)sender{

    DisplayInfoViewController *divc = [[DisplayInfoViewController alloc] init];
    divc.textView = self.nextAction;
    divc.title = @"Background Info";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:divc animated:YES];
    [divc release];
}

-(IBAction)actionDone:(id)sender{

    ActionViewController *avc = [[ActionViewController alloc] init];
    avc.title = @"Action";
    avc.nextAction = self.nextAction;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:avc animated:YES];
    [avc release];
}

@end
```

Here's the Header File:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface ContactDetailViewController : UITableViewController {

    NSString *name;
    NSString *date;
    NSString *nextAction;

    IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *usernameLabel;
    IBOutlet UITextField *nextActionTextField;
    IBOutlet UILabel *dateLabel;

    IBOutlet UIButton *contactInfoButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton *backgroundInfoButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton *actionDoneButton;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *date;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *nextAction;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *usernameLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *nextActionTextField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *dateLabel;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *contactInfoButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *backgroundInfoButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *actionDoneButton;

-(IBAction)displayContactInfo: (id)sender;
-(IBAction)displayBackgroundInfo: (id)sender;
-(IBAction)actionDone: (id)sender;


@end
```

However when I run it, I get the following error message:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key nameLabel.'

In IB I've hooked up the labels/buttons/textbox to the File's Owner (set the File's Owner Class to: ContactDetailViewController)

Anyone any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: added a screen shot of IB and connections:
Go to:
http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/44c65c7ef3.png

Regards,
Fiona

Answer (score 0):

Are you switching between platforms?
As in like nib built on old platform and used on the new one?
Try cleaning all targets may that would help.

Comment: Hi jAmi, Thanks for taking the time to look at it... No, I'm not switching between platforms... And I've tried cleaning.. I've deleted the nib and redone it. I was concerned that my method might be wrong.. does it look good to you? Also added an link to a screen shot of IB and connections in original message...

Comment: OK, may be the error is because you are subclassing UITableViewController.
Try UIViewController instead like 

@interface ContactDetailViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

Comment: Ok.. i tried it but getting the same error... same place.. where I attempt to return the view from the viewForHeaderInSection method.
Any other ideas?!

Comment: ContactHeaderView.xib has fileOwner type ContactDetailView and is being allocated with UIViewController class type. I think you should refine that(try making a seperate ContactHeaderView class if you dont already have one and then assign that as the FileOwner of ContactHeaderView.xib). If even this does not work then I m sorry I can't help you right now because I do not hav XCode installed . May be i will be able to help you when I get bak home after 3-4 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a solution.
In ContactDetailViewController, I create and IBOutlet UIView.
Then in viewForHeaderInSection I did the following:

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0){
        //UIViewController *chv = [[[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ContactHeaderView" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        //headerView = chv.view;
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ContactHeaderView" owner:self options:nil];
        headerView = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        self.nameLabel.text = self.name;
        self.nextActionTextField.text = self.nextAction;
        self.dateLabel.text = self.date;
        return headerView;
    }else{
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Finally in IB I connected the IBOutlet UIView created in ContactDetailViewController, to the view.

Thanks for your help jAmi.
Fiona